# Sencha Cmd v7 Select default value combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox

Current state: The combobox display by default a 0

Goal: I want to display "24/7" which is an option that appears inside its list if clicked.

Here is my combobox:

```
{
    xtype: "combobox",
    name: "horario",
    reference: "horarioCombo",
    queryMode: "local",
    label: i18n.t(
        "OSAccess.view.usuarios.tabs.configDefault.field.horario",
        "Horarios por defecto"
    ),
    bind: {
        hidden:
            "{!settingsGlobal.configuracion.sistemaSmartpass}",
        value: "{usuario.horarioId}",
        required:
            "{!isCreate && settingsGlobal.configuracion.sistemaSmartpass}"
    },
    displayField: "descripcion",
    valueField: "id",
    flex: 2,
    publishes: {
        selection: true
    },
    hidden: true,
    store: {
        type: "horarios",
        autoLoad: true
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of the `usuario.horarioId` in the model that you are binding. If its 0 the default value will be 0. Otherwise change the bind - value reference accordingly.

Comment: @AnandSingh , yes the default value is 0. I don't know what to put in the bind, can you tip me?

Comment: In the viewModel change the value for `usuario.horarioId` to "24/7", it will automatically apply in the combobox. Otherwise, you can use 'focus' event and then change the value to '24/7' in the event dynamically if user clicks or focuses the combobox.

`focus: function(combo){
combo.setValue('24/7');
}`